# Drupal Keeps Resetting it's Settings

Tags: caching

I'm using Drupal, and I'm having this weird issue with it. Multiple times in a day certain settings reset themselves temporarily. When I clear the cache, the issue is fixed for a while, but then I'll get an email from a confused client as to why the Meta tags are all of a sudden back to what they were before we updated them. This specific situation has happened about 4 times now on the same site.

Relatedly, Superfish's Supposition plugin was causing issues so I kept disabling it, only for supposition to automatically re-enable itself after a little while.

The strange thing is that I've used Drupal for other stuff, and I've *never* had that sort of problem.

I am using Memcached (1.4.4) with the Memcache Module for Drupal (7.x-1.0). Libmemcached version is 0.31 and the PECL extension version is 1.0.0, if that makes any difference. It's the only site which uses this.

Has anyone ever encountered this before? *Any* amount of help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems likely it would be related to the memcache config; are you able to switch to redis or use db caching temporarily to rule that out? I've had similar problems before when I've forgotten to set a reasonable prefix for the cache bin, but obviously that only applies if more than one site is using memcache. Also (and I'm sure this will confuse things more) meta tags are usually stored in the database, not in cache. Agree with @Shihan that you might want to flag this for migration to Drupal Answers, it's likely you'll get more Drupal-expert eyes on it there

Comment: @Clive flagged it. Anything more I need to do?

Comment: Nope, just sit an wait :) Acutally, if you want to do it quicker just delete this copy and re-ask it yourself on DA